# Pause an interval when hovering on div

Tags: jquery

I have set an interval on an array of divs that click through. I need a way to clear the interval when hovering over a specific div to pause the interval and then return the set interval when not hovering on that specific div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = ['#tog1', '#tog2', '#tog3', '#tog4', '#tog5', '#tog6', '#tog7', '#tog8', '#tog9'];

var index = 0;
setInterval(function () {
$(arr[index++]).trigger('click');
if (index == arr.length)
}, 4000);
</script>
```

So if I hover on a div called `.compBox` it needs to clear the interval and when non hovering return back to setinterval.

** UPDATE **

so using some of the advice below I am now here, So it would appear that it recognises me hovering over `.compBox` but the interval on the array isnt stopping:

```
var arr = ['#tog1', '#tog2', '#tog3', '#tog4', '#tog5', '#tog6', '#tog7', '#tog8', '#tog9', '#tog10'];
var index = 0;
var int = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("working")
    $(arr[index++]).trigger('click');
    if (index == arr.length)
        index = 0

}, 4000);


function handleInterval() {
    $('.compBox').hover(function() {
        //When the mouse enters the container, clear the interval
        clearInterval(int)
    }, function() {
        //When the mouse leaves the container, reset the interval
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("working")
    $(arr[index++]).trigger('click');
    if (index == arr.length)
        index = 0

}, 4000);
    });
}
handleInterval();
```

Comment: You're not resetting re-initializing your int variable as an interval on mouseleave. For your purposes, i suggest using @jcuenod solution instead, since it does not handle too many global variables, as mine does.

Comment: @SeanKwon I am struggling to get it work with the code I have, well struggling to understand what goes where tia that example, are you able to advise?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j2bdL8op/ i replaced your trigger click with console

Comment: @SeanKwon Right I get it now! I changed out the console.log for my triggers and it works perfectly. I understand what is happening here now, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a flag (`hovered_flag`) that prevents your timer from executing its function?

```js
var hovered_flag = false;

$(".dont_trigger").hover(function(e){
  hovered_flag = true;
  console.log("prevent triggering");
},function(e){
  hovered_flag = false;
  console.log("allow triggering");
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (hovered_flag) return
  console.log("trigger click");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.dont_trigger {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f44;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dont_trigger"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, even with the `hovered_flag` wouldn't the interval just keep running, just not able to execute the console.log?

Comment: @SeanKwon yes, the interval continues, the key is that it just `returns` rather than doing something. This will make a difference if the interval period is important (i.e. if it really matters that it takes 4s from the moment the div is no longer hovered).

Comment: I am struggling to implement this into the code I am using it seems to be acting quite erratically.  In the console its telling me its working on the interval it counts up and then creates a new instance of the log. Really odd I can't spot the pattern

Comment: I will accept this as the answer as the code base is sourced from this. However @SeanKwon answer was equally as good and he did help me a lot.

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out? I'm not sure that I understand the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

here's a code snippet from a slider i did some years back ... 
https://github.com/drmjo/jquery-slider/blob/master/js/jquery.uc-slider.js#L165

you can't really Pause in a sense you are thinking ... so i clear the interval all together and restart it on mouse events...

```
// here starts the initial auto play function.....

this.intervalID = setInterval(function(){

    pos = autoplay(pos, slideCount);

},options.autoplayTimer);


var intervalID = this.intervalID;   //making the intervalID passable

// autostop on mouseover  and start on mouse out... 
this.mouseleave(function(){
    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
      pos = autoplay(pos, slideCount);
    },options.autoplayTimer);
}); 

//Start the auto play on mouse leave... :)
this.mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var int = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("working")
    }, 1000);

    function handleInterval() {
        $('.compBox').hover(function() {
            //When the mouse enters the container, clear the interval
            clearInterval(int)
        }, function() {
            //When the mouse leaves the container, reset the interval
            int = setInterval(() => console.log("working"), 1000);
        });
    }
    handleInterval();
```

```css
.compBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compBox">
</div>
```

Here's my solution. Note that I've stored the interval as a variable so I can reset it when the mouse enters the target and restart the interval when the mouse leaves. Note that I'm using es6, but you can use vanilla js as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jquery-Timer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-timer/) plugin.